# Regex to allow a space instead of following numbers after first two letters

Tags: java, regex

I need a RegEx that allow a single space after two letters i.e. `AB123` should not be allowed but `AB 123` should be allowed ?

Comment: What have you tried from your side?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern will do the work: `^[a-zA-Z]{2} \d+$`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`[a-zA-Z]{2}` - match two letters (upper- or lowercase),

- match space

`\d+` - match one or more digits

`$` - match end of a string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/udCfmd/3)

Comment: it needs to be "after two letters"

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex `[a-zA-Z]{2}\s\S*`

`[a-zA-Z]` means character from a to Z

`{2}` means character twice

`\s` means white space

`\S` means non white space.

`*` duplicate with 0 or more

https://regex101.com/r/uWYci4/1